# TypeError: takes one positional argument but five were given

Tags: python, typeerror, argument-passing

```
def double_preceding(values):

    '''(list of ints)->None

    Update each value in a list with twice
    the preceding value, and the first item
    with 0.

    For example, if x has the value
    [1,2,3,4,5], after calling the
    double_preceding with argument x,
    x would have the value[0,2,4,6,8]

    >>>double_preceding(2,3,4,5,6)
    [0,4,6,8,10]
    >>>double_preceding(3,1,8,.5,10)
    [0,6,2,16,1] 
    '''
    if values != []:
        temp = values[0]
        values[0] = 0
        for i in range(0, len(values)):
            double = 2 * temp
            temp = values[i]
            values[i] = double
    return #None
```

So what am I doing wrong? I don't see a problem anywhere and I've been trying to fix it for an hour now.

I fixed the code:

```
def double_preceding(values):

    if values != 0:  
            temp = values[0]
            values[0] = 0
         for i in range(1, len(values)):
               double = 2 * temp
               temp = values[i]
               values[i] = double
    print(values)
    return#None
```

Comment: That's a pretty concise, explicit and clear error message isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your function accepts only one argument, while you are passing 5 to it. Replace:

```
>>>double_preceding(2,3,4,5,6)
[0,4,6,8,10]
>>>double_preceding(3,1,8,.5,10)
[0,6,2,16,1]
```

with:

```
>>>double_preceding([2,3,4,5,6])
[0,4,6,8,10]
>>>double_preceding([3,1,8,.5,10])
[0,6,2,16,1]
```

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add print(argument) in this case print(values) to get a printout of the argument. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you decided to pass in the literal values of the list instead of passing it a variable that contains a list. For ex.

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

double_preceding(x)

This way your function should work if you just pass it x depending on what code you have inside the function. Can you post the actual code that's inside the function?

Comment: So I was given an example to work off of but the problem gave and argument called "values" I could use x and that is fine but I still get the: function takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given.

Comment: so trading values for x it's arbitrary.if x != []:
        temp = x[0]
        x[0] = 0
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            double = 2 * temp
            temp = x[i]
            x[i] = double